# Django ImportError: No module named 'django.utils'

Tags: python, django, jenkins

Делаю блог с помощью Django, первый раз его использую. Для сборки проекта и тестов использую Jenkins. Сборка не удается, получаю ошибку:

```
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
ImportError: No module named 'django.utils'
```

Раньше в models.py была запись:

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

На нее тоже получала ошибку, когда заменила на `import datetime` проблема решилась.

Такое же решение для `from django.utils.version import get_version` не работает

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: Какая версия Django при выполнении тестов?